# Swift UI ScrollView layout behaviour

Tags: swiftui, layout

Does ScrollView in SwiftUI proposes no height for its children.

```
ScrollView {
    Color.clear
           .frame(idealHeight: 200)
           .background(.blue)
}
```

will result in [image]

As written in frame documentation

> The size proposed to this view is the size proposed to the frame, limited by any constraints specified, and with any ideal dimensions **specified replacing any corresponding unspecified dimensions** in the proposal.

So does it mean scrollView doesn't propose any height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ScrollView` with a vertical axis does not offer a height because its height is potentially infinite.
So the child views adopt their `idealHeight`. Which in the case of a view that normally uses all the height offered, like `Color`, or `Rectangle`, corresponds to the magic number **10**.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var height: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Rectangle()
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear {
                                height = geo.size.height
                            }
                    }
                )
        }
        .overlay(Text(height.description), alignment: .bottom)
    }
}
```

[image: proof]

Note that we also find this magic number **10** (putting aside the `ScrollView`) if we ask the same `Rectangle` to use its `idealHeight`, using the modifier `.fixedSize`

```
struct SwiftUIView101: View {
    @State private var height: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fixedSize()
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear {
                                height = geo.size.height
                            }
                    }
                )
            Text(height.description)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: proof 2]